# getting FileNotFoundException even thought the file is there

Tags: android, inputstream

I am trying to access a file for xml parsing with this:

```
InputStream inputStream = context.getAssets().open("/mnt/sdcard/cat/bird/flowers.xml");
```

When it runs i get the following error:

```
06-13 23:13:22.620: W/System.err(3118): java.io.FileNotFoundException: /mnt/sdcard/cat/bird/flowers.xml
06-13 23:13:22.620: W/System.err(3118):     at android.content.res.AssetManager.openAsset(Native Method)
06-13 23:13:22.620: W/System.err(3118):     at android.content.res.AssetManager.open(AssetManager.java:314)
06-13 23:13:22.620: W/System.err(3118):     at android.content.res.AssetManager.open(AssetManager.java:288)
```

I have checked the spelling of the file and i have checked the location several times. The file is there and correctly named. What is going on here?

Thanks

Comment: If you down vote a post, why not leave an explanation as to why you downvoted. This way the poster can improve their questions. Can't see any reason why you would downvote.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`getAssets().open(...)` is used to access files which you have packaged with the .apk file by placing them in the project's `/assets` directory.

Trying to open a file with this path...

```
/mnt/sdcard/cat/bird/flowers.xml
```

...means the `AssetManager` will try to look for a packaged file which you originally placed in your project with the following path...

```
/assets/mnt/sdcard/cat/bird/flowers.xml
```

Comment: I changed it to searching for a normal file and NOT one in the assests. Now it works. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Make sure you have the following permission. (may not be needed for just reading). Also on some devices reading from sdcard has been restricted.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

Also do NOT use hardcoded paths, use the following to get external storage path.

```
String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/cat/bird/flowers.xml";
```

Comment: I have the permission and the path is not hardcoded. I just took out the extra noise to show you what is actually being used. This way i could post less code but get my point across.

Answer (score 0):

The `getAssets()` is generally used to get access to files in the assets folder in your project.  You should use something like:

```
InputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream("//sdcard//cat//bird//flowers.xml");
```